# .NET 8 MapFallbackToFile fails when "." is in the last URL Section

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes, .net-8.0

I'm trying to configure a very basic "Not Found" catch all for a .NET 8 application that is only using static files without MVC or controllers in Kestrel.

I ended up using the `MapFallbackToFile` as in the example

```
public void ConfigureApp(IApplicationBuilder app) 
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseEndpoints((IEndpointRouteBuilder builder) => {
            builder.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) => {
                context.Response.Redirect($"/view/index.html{context.Request.QueryString}");
            });

            builder.MapFallbackToFile("/view/notFound.html");
    });
}
```

It seems to be working fine for any of the URLs unless there is a `.` somewhere. These URLs are correctly showing the `notFound.html`

```
https://localhost/no/such/file
https://localhost/no/su.ch/file
```

But URLs like these do not

```
https://localhost/no/such/fi.le
```

I'm guessing that it has something to do with it trying to treat it as a file type extension or something of the sort but is there any way to stop this from happening?

**UPDATE**

Just adding that `MapFallbackToFile` might also be completely wrong for handling Not Found but I haven't found a better way to handle it with only static files

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative to using the `MapFallbackToFile` that seems to work a lot better. I just added Middleware to check the `StatusCode`

```
public void ConfigureApp(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        await next();
        if(context.Response.StatusCode == 404) {
            context.Response.Redirect($"/view/notFound.html{context.Request.QueryString}");
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not going to say this is the answer just yet because I'm still not completely sure about it and hoping for insight from those who know better